# Unable to interact with third party angularJs application with phantomJs,capybara

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I am unable to interact with angularjs third party application. I have installed capybara-ng, capybara/angularjs and have changed the DSL to angularJs DSL.

I am using ruby2.0.3,phantomjs-2.0.0-windows.

The DOMs are not fully loaded and I am unable to proceed further.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you really are using phantomjs 2.0+, and turn on js_errors in your poltergeist driver config.  The usual cause of this is the version of phantomjs you're using missing Function.prototype.bind support, which will show up in the js errors.  You can  polyfill support for it, but phantomjs 2 is supposed to have support built in